# PHP array extract

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a querystring :

```
"condition=good;condition=not-good&features=ABS&features=ESP&features=ENT&brand=Honda&model=Traffic"
```

***please note duplicate parameter**

I use this function to convert and - get also duplicate key - to array :

```
function proper_parse_str($str) {
  # result array
  $arr = array();

  # split on outer delimiter
  $pairs = explode('&', $str);

  # loop through each pair
  foreach ($pairs as $i) {
    # split into name and value
    list($name,$value) = explode('=', $i, 2);

    # if name already exists
    if( isset($arr[$name]) ) {
      # stick multiple values into an array
      if( is_array($arr[$name]) ) {
        $arr[$name][] = $value;
      }
      else {
        $arr[$name] = array($arr[$name], $value);
      }
    }
    # otherwise, simply stick it in a scalar
    else {
      $arr[$name] = $value;
    }
  }

  # return result array
  return $arr;
}
```

In order to echo html I use this :

```
//using the above function
$array=proper_parse_str($string);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $t) {
            $e .="<li>".$t."</li>";
        }
        $mkey .="<ul><li><b>".$key."</b><ul>".$e."</ul></li></ul>";
    } else {
        $tt ="<li>".$value."</li>";
        $mkey .="<ul><li><b>".$key."</b><ul>".$tt."</ul></li></ul>";
    }
}  
echo $mkey;
```

to get :

```
Condition
   good
   not-good
Features
   ABS
   ESP
   ENT
Brand
   Honda
Model
   Traffic
```

but I get :

```
Condition
   good
   not-good
Features
   **good
   **not-good
   ABS
   ESP
   ENT
Brand
   Honda
Model
   Traffic
```

Please help me..

Comment: Why are the first two pairs separated by a ; instead of a &?

Comment: Where is the value `$k` being set?

Comment: Do a `print_r( $arr )` to check if your construction is actually correct. The print-out code looks a bit incomplete.

Comment: @Nadec: I would say type since there's nothing in the code to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function proper_parse_str($str) {
  # result array
  $arr = array();

  # split on outer delimiter
  $pairs = explode('&', $str);

  # loop through each pair
  foreach ($pairs as $i) {
    # split into name and value
    list($name,$value) = explode('=', $i, 2);
    $arr[$name][] = $value;
  }

  # return result array
  return $arr;
}
//using the above function
        $array=proper_parse_str("condition=good&condition=not-good&features=ABS&features=ESP&features=ENT&brand=Honda&model=Traffic");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<li>$key<ol>";
    foreach ( $value as $k => $v )
    {
        echo "<li>$v</li>";
    }
    echo "</ol></li>";
}  
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Manny smart / experts guys here...thank's this solution works too.

Answer (score 5):

You never initialized `$e` in your echoing code.  So it will always just append the new values rather than resetting.  Try this:

```
$array=proper_parse_str($string);
$mkey = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value)  {
    if (is_array($value)) { 
        $e = '';
        foreach($value as $t){
            $e .="<li>".$t."</li>"; 
        }  
        $mkey .="<ul><li><b>".$k."</b><ul>".$e."</ul></li></ul>";
    }  else {        
        $tt ="<li>".$value."</li>";
        $mkey .="<ul><li><b>".$key."</b><ul>".$tt."</ul></li></ul>";
    }   
}  
echo $mkey;
```

The moral of the story: *always initialize your variables*...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)? (Assuming what you're doing is typical to parsing a GET argument string).

Comment: It's not identical (I was going to say the same thing, but then realized the difference).  Basically this simulates array syntax without the need for `[]`.  With `parse_str`, identical keys overwrite, so `foo=bar&foo=baz` would only result in `foo=baz`.  But his implementation would transform it to `foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz`.  Slightly different (and not fitting with the spec), but it is different...

Comment: Ah, good catch. Seems almost easier to catch these duplicates and adjust them, then parse with the native function. I guess to each their own.

Comment: That's what I would likely do if I had to solve this problem myself.  That way you're still coming up with valid query strings, and have the benefit of the decoding/etc that the native function gives...

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your query string? If so, you may want to look at using arrays. E.g.

```
condition[]=good&condition[]=not-good&features[]=ABS&features[]=ESP&features[]=ENT&brand[]=Honda&model[]=Traffic
```

gives:

```
array
  'condition' => 
    array
      0 => string 'good' (length=4)
      1 => string 'not-good' (length=8)
  'features' => 
    array
      0 => string 'ABS' (length=3)
      1 => string 'ESP' (length=3)
      2 => string 'ENT' (length=3)
  'brand' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Honda' (length=5)
  'model' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Traffic' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the string generation a bit more simple using an array join.

```
$mkey = '';
foreach ( proper_parse_str( $string ) as $key => $value )
{
    if ( is_array( $value ) )
        $value = implode( '</li><li>', $value );

    $mkey .= '<li><b>' . $key . '</b><ul><li>' . $value . '</li></ul></li>';
}
echo $mkey;
```

Regardless of that, I would suggest you to always use an array as the value holder in your array to make your structure more static.